# How do you limit the maximum number of results with Searchkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, elasticsearch, searchkick

I'm using [Searchkick](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick) to connect to an ElasticSearch server that indexes hundreds of thousands of documents. However, paging through *all* results frequently results in a crash. How can I tell the `search` method to return only a maximum of *n* results?

Comment: We'd like to see what you tried, and an explanation why it didn't help you. Please read "[ask]", including the links in that page.

Comment: Why downvote? this is usefull when you dont want your users to scroll within the millions of records you have, cause most likely they wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Taken directly from the `README` in the link you posted:

```
Product.search "apples", where: {in_stock: true}, limit: 10, offset: 50
```

`limit: 10` will result in a maximum of `10` results being returned.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear. I would like to limit the total number of results returned overall, not how many come back in a particular page. Suppose there are 1,000,000 documents, but I never want the number of results available to paginate to be more than 1,000.

Comment: That's strange behaviour; why would you want to limit the number of available pages? At a guess, it might be possible by doing: `Product.limit(xxxxx).search "apples", where: {in_stock: true}, limit: 10, offset: 50`

Comment: Because when you have millions of documents, and an index page that gets crawled by Google, you run into problems when it asks for `limit: 1000, offset: 1958`. I guess a better way to phrase the question might be: how do you cap the maximum offset?

Comment: i am building the query with `body: ` as described here - https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#advanced-search - how/where do i pass in `limit:` and `offset:` when building query with `body` ?